# R How to summarize two different groups after initial group_by

Tags: r

I have the following I would like to do in one go instead of making two different results and doing a union:

```
delivery_stats= data.frame(service=c("UberEats", "Seamless","UberEats", "Seamless"),
                            status = c("OnTime", "OnTime", "Late", "Late"),
                            totals = c(235, 488, 32, 58))   

ds1 = filter(delivery_stats, service =="UberEats") %>%
         group_by(service, status) %>% 
         summarise(count_status = sum(totals)) %>%
         mutate(avg_of_status = count_status/sum(count_status))

#now do the same for Seamless, then union...
```

Comment: I think you get the results you want if you just don't filter at the start. You're already grouping by `service` so the calculations will happen within each service.

Comment: @H1 I had completely sabotaged myself, have no idea why!

Comment: Please don't use `Rstudio` tag for programming related questions. `Rstudio` tag is reserved only for issues related to RStudio IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Provided I have understood you correctly, do you mean this?

```
delivery_stats %>%
    group_by(service) %>%
    mutate(n = sum(totals)) %>%
    transmute(
        status,
        count_status = totals,
        avg_of_status = count_status/n)
## A tibble: 4 x 4
## Groups:   service, status [4]
#  service  status count_status avg_of_status
#  <fct>    <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#1 UberEats OnTime          235         0.880
#2 Seamless OnTime          488         0.894
#3 UberEats Late             32         0.120
#4 Seamless Late             58         0.106
```

Explanation: First group by `service` to calculate the sum of `totals` by `service`; then group by `service` and `status` to calculate the mean (across `service`) of `count_status = totals`.

Answer (score 0):

You also try base R using `ave` with the help of `within`.

```
res <- within(delivery_stats, {
  count_status <- ave(totals, service, status, FUN=mean)
  avg_of_status <- count_status / ave(totals, service, FUN=sum)
})
res
#    service status totals avg_of_status count_status
# 1 UberEats OnTime    235     0.8801498          235
# 2 Seamless OnTime    488     0.8937729          488
# 3 UberEats   Late     32     0.1198502           32
# 4 Seamless   Late     58     0.1062271           58
```

Answer (score -1):

As said above, I didn't have to filter and it would have worked fine for both groups:

```
delivery_stats= data.frame(service=c("UberEats", "Seamless","UberEats", "Seamless"),
                            status = c("OnTime", "OnTime", "Late", "Late"),
                            totals = c(235, 488, 32, 58))



ds1 =    group_by(delivery_stats, service, status) %>% 
         summarise(count_status = sum(totals)) %>%
         mutate(avg_of_status = count_status/sum(count_status))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   service [2]
  service  status count_status avg_of_status
  <fct>    <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Seamless Late             58         0.106
2 Seamless OnTime          488         0.894
3 UberEats Late             32         0.120
4 UberEats OnTime          235         0.880
```

Comment: You don't need `count_status = sum(totals)` since you only have a single value (per defined groups); see my earlier answer.

Comment: but you as well do mutate (n = sum(totals)), what is the difference?

Comment: You are grouping by `service` *and* `status`; at that level you only have a single entry, so there is nothing to aggregate/`summarise`. In my answer, I group by `service` only, and then calculate the sum across `status`; after that, I group by `service` *and* `status` and calculate the average by dividing numbers by the `service`-level sum. There is no need to `summarise` anywhere; `mutate`/`transmute` suffices.